# Stanford CoreNLP Output

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

Is there anyway to generate this output from the Stanford CoreNLP server?
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1K2g7nBzHgOpiBQZFRQBNWbylIvCANsdQ?usp=sharing

I have tried running the server on sample sentences with the following annotators:
'tokenize','ssplit','pos','lemma','depparse','natlog','openie', 'ner', 'parse'
and get similar data, just in a different format.

I am assuming that the format I am trying to get the output into is the default output from an older version of CoreNLP. Is there any way to get the output in the format needed?

Answer (score 0):

Output format is fixed and it cannot be configured out of the box, however you can de-serialize the output and convert it in required format. You can use @dataclasses based design pattern to achieve the operation optimally!

Comment: Thank you! I am not too familiar with Python. so what does it meant to de-serialize the output?

Comment: When you receive a response from a web-api, it's generally a string of the json body. You need to covert it back to the json (roughly this can be called as de-serialization), then use the object properties accordingly.

For more info on de-serialization in python, please read https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/deserialize-json-to-object-in-python/ article, you may also want to check some other blogs and youtube videos if you are completely new to the ares.